# Multiple datePicker in same page angular Material (Angular material 8.2.3)

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I will try to put a second datepicker in my page and not work.
The first one work fine the second one don't open the calendar,

my code below:

```
<mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="test" type="text"
                    formControlName="dataRilascio">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="test" type="text"
                    formControlName="dataScadenza"  >
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

what is the problem? i can't figure out.

Comment: the code is ok, be sure the name of the FormControls are correct -I suppose that, when you define the formGroup, you has not dataScadenza or dataRilascio, see a stackblitz that work:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5c4kq?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.ts

Comment: i think there are conflict with other stuff inside the controller but i put the code inside my app and work fine